# Django- restrict users to access urls

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

i'm creating a app.it has manytomany field to store data about class and students.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^class/(?p<title>[-\w]+)/(?p<id>[\d]+)/',views.list,name ='list'),
```

Basically one `user`(Teacher) can create many `class_room` .Each `class_room` have one `title` and many `students` following in that class.

**problem is:**

Each `class_room` have unique `url`. Eg (mywebsite.com/science/88/) this link is access only for following students not for anonymous user.This is a loop hole if any non following students try some random `url` like this they could see the page (mywebsite.com/maths/2500/).

**How to restrict a student from access a page which he is not following?**

Comment: show your view code please

Comment: @Bear Brown sorry for late response Brown. i get one solution using queries it is working well. Thanks for response :)

Comment: and thank you two)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `UserPassesTestMixin` [mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) can be used to this effect. Basically, write a View Class that implements the `test_func`function. This function has access to `self` so you can read the URL and the user. if the test_func returns `True`, the user is allowed to go on, otherwise is passed to access control (probably redirected to the login form if configured).